# Looking for sample with @ManyToMany + Repository completion stage

Tags: java, sql, json, playframework, ebean

Can you give me an example of a project that covers @ManyToMany with the use of Repository (Completion Stage)

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Can you add more details about what exactly you want? 
There are many examples available for many to many relationship for reference you can go through these links.
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many
or https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23507_01/Platform.20073/RepositoryGuide/html/s1204repositoryexamplehmanytomany01.html

Comment: Hello, I would like to use ManyToMany association not only for Eban / Hibernate, but, in my playframework 2.6.x ++ ( using of course Repository files )